# Unable to create react set up on macbook m1

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am unable to create a react app on mac m1 . I don't know how to proceed with the following problem.

```
prateekshukla@iamkeetarp shopping-app % npx create-react-app-frontend
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app-frontend - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'create-react-app-frontend@latest' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/prateekshukla/.npm/_logs/2022-03-06T14_38_24_143Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Read the error message carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a package that does not exist :

```
GET https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app-frontend - Not found
```

The package you are looking for is `create-react-app` (no `-frontend`).

So what you should write is:

```sh
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Check out [React's documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app) for more info.